# One-line Python3 sorted file list of a directory

Tags: python-3.x

Using Python 3, how to get the list of files in a directory sorted by size with a one-line only command?

Answer (score 0):

```py
sorted(os.scandir('directory'), key=lambda e:e.stat().st_size)
```